# Colocando scroll na horizontal

Tags: html, css

Queria colocar um *scroll* na horizontal, para que possa ser acessado em telas de celular. Como faço isso?

```css
.menu_topo_geral {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #616161;
}
.menu_topo_geral div {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    float: left;
    border: 0 solid #484848;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
.menu_topo_geral div:hover {
    background: #484848;
}
.menu_topo_geral div:active {
    background: #323232;
}
```

```html
<div class='menu_topo_geral'>
            <div class='bg-grey-2'>MENU 1</div>
            <div>MENU 2</div>
            <div>MENU 3</div>
            <div>MENU 4</div>
            <div>MENU 5</div>
            <div>MENU 6</div>
            <div>MENU 7</div>
            <div>MENU 8</div>
            <div>MENU 9</div>
            <div>MENU 10</div>
            <div>MENU 11</div>
            <div>MENU 12</div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assim ?

Uma dica é colocar a função `calc` no `width` da classe `content-menu`:

```
width: calc(85px * 12);
```

Você tem que calcular mais ou menos qual será o tamanho de cada ítem do MENU e fazer uma multiplicação básica para definir o tamanho do `content-menu`. Daí ele não vai sobrar espaços no final.

Manjou ?

```css
.menu_topo_geral {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
.content-menu {
  width: calc(85px * 12);
  background: #616161;
  display: table;
}
.menu_topo_geral .content-menu div {
  line-height: 50px;
  float: left;
  border: 0 solid #484848;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='menu_topo_geral'>
  <div class="content-menu">
    <div>MENU 1</div>
    <div>MENU 2</div>
    <div>MENU 3</div>
    <div>MENU 4</div>
    <div>MENU 5</div>
    <div>MENU 6</div>
    <div>MENU 7</div>
    <div>MENU 8</div>
    <div>MENU 9</div>
    <div>MENU 10</div>
    <div>MENU 11</div>
    <div>MENU 12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Entendi sim,  mas juntei a sua resposta e a do @Lucas Costa para chegar no resultado desejado, segue o link https://jsfiddle.net/8a76rm5t/2/ .muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Para habilitar o scroll na horizontal você pode usar [overflow-x](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x) na classe do elemento que poderá ser expandida (exemplo a `menu_topo_geral`):

```
.menu_topo_geral {
    overflow-x: visible;
}
```

**JSFiddle**:  https://jsfiddle.net/8a76rm5t/1/

Comment: Já tentei isso, e não deu certo. Tem como editar sua resposta com o código funcionando?

Comment: No seu caso @HugoBorges, o truque está o no `width` da classe `menu_topo_geral` que está em 100%. O que ele vai fazer é quebrar a linha por usar o tamanho total do viewport. O ideal é setar um tamanho fixo (em px), para ele aplicar o overflow. Em cenário de teste, deixei como 200% para você ver: https://jsfiddle.net/8a76rm5t/

Comment: @Luas Costa, entendi, porém vc não entendeu minha idéia. Preciso que o menu ocupe 100% da página, e quando tiver muitas opções ele cria um scroll apenas no menu, e não na página toda. Igual a esse sistema de abas que o Mr. Felix me ajudou http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172893/como-colocar-um-scroll-no-sistema-de-abas apenas as abas se movem, e o conteúdo não.

Comment: Atualizei @HugoBorges, veja se é isso: https://jsfiddle.net/8a76rm5t/1/

Comment: é isso sim, porém notei que vc colocou '.menu_topo_geral {
    width: 200%;
}' o menu fica uma parte em branco, a rolagem tem que parar quando as opções do menu terminar.

Comment: Pois é. Para que haja a rolagem, o tamanho ter de ser fixo, como citei. O ideal no caso, é deixar o tamanho dos menus fixos.

Comment: tem como deixa o tamanho dos menus fixo, e quando o texto for grande ele altera o tamanho para acompanhar ?